# TypeScript issue when using Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have:

```
const neuroResponses = await Promise.allSettled(neuroRequests);

  const ret = neuroResponses.filter(response => response?.value?.data?.result[0]?.generated_text?.length > 0).map(({ value }) => value.data.result[0]?.generated_text);
```

But I get a TypeScript issue:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseSettledResult<AxiosResponse<any>>'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'PromiseRejectedResult'.
```

Is there a better way to type this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional chaining doesn't change the fact that, from a type perspective, you're trying to use a property that isn't there. It just defends against your proceeding if the property contains the value `undefined`. You're still trying to use a property that may not exist on the type.

You can use a type guard to filter out the failed responses. For instance, an inline type guard:

```typescript
const neuroResponses = await Promise.allSettled(neuroRequests);
const ret = neuroResponses
    .filter(response => "value" in response && response.value.data?.result[0]?.generated_text?.length > 0)
    .map(({ value }) => value.data.result[0]?.generated_text);
```

If you do this a lot, you might want a type guard function:

```typescript
function isSuccessful<T>(response: PromiseSettledResult<T>): response is PromiseFulfilledResult<T> {
    return "value" in response;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```typescript
const neuroResponses = await Promise.allSettled(neuroRequests);
const ret = neuroResponses
    .filter(isSuccessful) // ***
    .filter(response => response.value.data?.result[0]?.generated_text?.length > 0)
    .map(({ value }) => value.data.result[0]?.generated_text);
```

Or

```typescript
const neuroResponses = await Promise.allSettled(neuroRequests);
const ret = neuroResponses
    .filter(response => isSuccessful(response) && response.value.data?.result[0]?.generated_text?.length > 0)
    .map(({ value }) => value.data.result[0]?.generated_text);
```